# Chargify Direct API ID location in dashboard

Tags: chargify

Where do I find my API ID, as opposed to the API secret or the API Key, when using it in a Chargify Direct integration?

The description of the Direct form is in https://docs.chargify.com/chargify-direct-introduction, but I can't find clear indication of where the API ID is obtained from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chargify Direct uses API v2 - here's how you generate both an ID and a key:

http://help.chargify.com/integrations/api-keys-chargify-direct.html